# GCC: invalid literal constant: pool needs to be closer

Tags: gcc, arm

I am trying to compile this inline code for armv4t chip,

```
asm ("LDR   R2, =a1");
```

gcc replies that

invalid literal constant: pool needs to be closer

I tried to move a1 near the function, but still the same error.

How to fix this error?

Comment: `a1` is a register name; can you try another label to see if it works? Did you mean a label or the value `0xa1`?  You can use, `asm("ldr r2,=a1\nb 1f\n .ltorg\n 1:\n")` which should always work but usually you don't need this.

Comment: Since you are using gcc, how about using extended asm and listing a1 as an input?

Answer (score 2):

Just stolen from the ARM site (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Babbfdih.html):

> The offset from the pc to the value in the literal pool must be less than 4KB. You are responsible for ensuring that there is a literal pool within range. See LTORG directive for more information.

so possibly the variable `a1` is defined somewhere outside of this 4k, this is what the assembler sees as invalid so it generates the error message.

There is a lot more info at http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/February_2006/freertos_ARM_Error_invalid_literal_constant_pool_nee_1448037.html and [ARM + gcc: don't use one big .rodata section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014449/arm-gcc-dont-use-one-big-rodata-section)

Some other sources (http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/68111 - German) suggest that the flag `-ffunction-sections` should be added to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks all for help. Adding -ffunction-sections flags works for me so far, but .ltorg does not work.